# DateTime TryParse Exact returning 0001:01:01

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse 
DateTime string `'28/3/2014`
with method:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/3/2014", "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy",
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                       out d);
```

And its always returning me `0001:01:01`.

Can you tell how to set conversion parameters?
I tried setting

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal
```

With no effects

`28/3/2014` is a example. Date could be also like `28/12/2014`

Comment: Well, first and foremost, when using any `TryParse` style method, you should check what the *return* value is. It's returning `false` here, which is telling you that the parse *failed*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: And yet none of the answers say that...

Comment: @leppie Now, there is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern must be

```
"dd'/'M'/'yyyy"
```

Refer to the article [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @szpic - really? Have you taken the 5 seconds or so it takes to try this to confirm that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

[Hamlet Hakobyans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22707717/447156) is right. But I want to add some explanation at least.

Let's analyze your question step by step:

You said your string is `'28/3/2014` but you used `28/3/2014` in your example. I assume, `28/3/2014` is the right string for your case.

So, your real code is;

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/3/2014", "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", 
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out d);
```

In such a case, you don't need to use `'` for your `/` delimiters but this doesn't break your code. Because `'` is a *literal string delimiter* and it's still valid for such a case.

But [`MM` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) is for `01` to `12`, that doesn't fit for month value which is `3`. You should use [`M` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) which is for `1` to `12`.

> And its always returning me 0001:01:01

Because your `TryParseExact` returns `false` (because your format doesn't fit with your string) and from [it's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> result
>
> Type: System.DateTime
>
> When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to
>   the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or
>   MinValue if the conversion failed**.

`0001:01:01` is equal to [`DateTime.MinValue` field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and other parts also..). That's why you get this value.

Finally, your code should be;

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/3/2014", "dd/M/yyyy",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out d);
```

And if you want `28/3/2014` as `string` (`DateTime` does not have a format) a result, you have a few options;

If your current thread culture's [`DateSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is / and [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `dd/m/yyyy`, you don't need to use anything. Just;

```
Console.WriteLine(d); //This will be enough.
```

If it is not, you can use [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Or you can escape your `/` no matter which culture you use like;

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd'/'M'/'yyyy"));
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(@"dd\/M\/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input string month has no leading 0, so you can try this:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/03/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

or

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/3/2014", "dd/M/yyyy", 
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("28/3/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format of the input number for months. You have set the format to "MM" but you pass as parameter only 3 . Try 28/03/2014 ("03" instead of simple "3").
By the way, the format string can be simply "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy".
Check it on  http://dotnetfiddle.net/I3Dyod

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally left off the seconds part and was trying to translate this:

```
DateTime.TryParse(@"1/1/2000 00:00:000", out DateTime dtLastRun);
```

It should have been:

```
DateTime.TryParse(@"1/1/2000 00:00:00:000", out DateTime dtLastRun);
```

What I can't figure out why is DateTime was returning a DateTime2 response. But regardless, if you have an invalid string you will get the default time returned.